# How to detect cheeks using openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, dlib

I am working on a virtual make-up using Python, openCV, dlib. Currently, I can get the facial landmarks like lips, nose, jaw etc. But I am quite unsure on getting the points of the cheeks.

Are they any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using dlib 68 facial landmarks, here are the ROIs of the 2 cheeks:

```
from imutils import face_utils

#face detection part

#rect is the face detected
shape = predictor(gray_img, rect)
shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

img[shape[29][1]:shape[33][1], shape[54][0]:shape[12][0]] #right cheeks
img[shape[29][1]:shape[33][1], shape[4][0]:shape[48][0]] #left cheek
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. It was helpful.
May I know how you derived the ROIs of the cheeks? 
Are there any documentation?

Comment: I just look at the figure and choose what coordinates form the 2 cheeks, you can also change it to fit your program.